# iOS dylib : lib not loaded crash at Runtime - Using same pod in custom framework and xcode project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Using same pod in custom framework and xcode project, while at the time of running project I got run time error dyld: Library not loaded: Referenced from: *** Custom Framework .image not found error

Answer (score 0):

Framework .image not found error.
If you create one Xcode framework, it is recommended to use Build Setings/Mach-O Type with Static Library.

[image]

Comment: The above solution doesn't work, I am still getting dyld Library not loaded for the pod framework which is common for custom framework and the project to which it is added.

Comment: Is this problem caused by custom framework or pod framework?

Comment: When I add custom framework to my project then I get above mentioned error.